# React & cloudflare image upload Fail

Tags: reactjs, django, cloudflare

I am doing web development with Django and React.

I was working on implementing a feature to upload images using CloudFlare.

My code is like the image picture.

```
// UploadPhotos.tsx 

import {
  Box,
  Button,
  Container,
  FormControl,
  Heading,
  Input,
  VStack,
} from "@chakra-ui/react";
import { useMutation } from "@tanstack/react-query";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { getUploadURL, uploadImage } from "../api";
import useHostOnlyPage from "../components/HostOnlyPage";
import ProtectedPage from "../components/ProtectedPage";

interface IForm {
  file: FileList;
}

interface IUploadURLResponse {
  id: string;
  uploadURL: string;
}

export default function UploadPhotos() {
  const { register, handleSubmit, watch } = useForm<IForm>();
  const { roomPk } = useParams();

  // const mutation = useMutation(
  //   {
  //   mutationFn: getUploadURL, 
  //   onSuccess: (data: any) => {
  //     console.log(data);
  //   },
  //   }
  // );

  const uploadURLMutation = useMutation(
    {
      mutationFn: getUploadURL, 
      onSuccess: (data: IUploadURLResponse) => {
        uploadImageMutation.mutate({
          uploadURL: data.uploadURL,
          file: watch("file"),
        });
      },
    });

  const uploadImageMutation = useMutation(
    {
      mutationFn: uploadImage, 
      onSuccess: (data: any) => {
        console.log(data);
      },
    });


  
  useHostOnlyPage();
  const onSubmit = (data: any) => {
    uploadURLMutation.mutate();
  };
  return (
    <ProtectedPage>
      <Box
        pb={40}
        mt={10}
        px={{
          base: 10,
          lg: 40,
        }}
      >
        <Container>
          <Heading textAlign={"center"}>Upload a Photo</Heading>
          <VStack
            as="form"
            onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}
            spacing={5}
            mt={10}
          >
            <FormControl>
              <Input {...register("file")} type="file" accept="image/*" />
            </FormControl>
            <Button type="submit" w="full" colorScheme={"red"}>
              Upload photos
            </Button>
          </VStack>
        </Container>
      </Box>
    </ProtectedPage>
  );
}
```

This is a api.tsx  file code

```
// api.tsx

import Cookie from "js-cookie";
import { QueryFunctionContext } from "@tanstack/react-query";
import axios from "axios";

const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/",
  withCredentials: true,
});

export const getRooms = () =>
  instance.get("rooms/").then((response) => response.data);

export const getRoom = ({ queryKey }: QueryFunctionContext) => {
  const [_, roomPk] = queryKey;
  return instance.get(`rooms/${roomPk}`).then((response) => response.data);
};

export const getRoomReviews = ({ queryKey }: QueryFunctionContext) => {
  const [_, roomPk] = queryKey;
  return instance
    .get(`rooms/${roomPk}/reviews`)
    .then((response) => response.data);
};

export const getMe = () =>
  instance.get(`users/me`).then((response) => response.data);

export const logOut = () =>
  instance
    .post(`users/log-out`, null, {
      headers: {
        "X-CSRFToken": Cookie.get("csrftoken") || "",
      },
    })
    .then((response) => response.data);

export const githubLogIn = (code: string) =>
  instance
    .post(
      `users/github`,
      { code },
      {
        headers: {
          "X-CSRFToken": Cookie.get("csrftoken") || "",
        },
      }
    )
    .then((response) => response.status);

export const kakaoLogin = (code: string) =>
  instance
    .post(
      `users/kakao`,
      { code },
      {
        headers: {
          "X-CSRFToken": Cookie.get("csrftoken") || "",
        },
      }
    )
    .then((response) => response.status);


export interface IUsernameLoginVariables {
    username: string;
    password: string;
}
export interface IUsernameLoginSuccess {
    ok: string;
}
export interface IUsernameLoginError {
    error: string;
}

export const usernameLogIn = ({
  username,
  password,
}: IUsernameLoginVariables) =>
  instance.post(
    `users/log-in`,
    { username, password },
    {
      headers: {
        "X-CSRFToken": Cookie.get("csrftoken") || "",
      },
    }
  );

export const getAmenities = () =>
  instance.get(`rooms/amenities`).then((response) => response.data);

export const getCategories = () =>
  instance.get(`categories`).then((response) => response.data);

export interface IUploadRoomVariables {
  name: string;
  country: string;
  city: string;
  price: number;
  rooms: number;
  toilets: number;
  description: string;
  address: string;
  pet_friendly: boolean;
  kind: string;
  amenities: number[];
  category: number;
}

export const uploadRoom = (variables: IUploadRoomVariables) =>
  instance
    .post(`rooms/`, variables, {
      headers: {
        "X-CSRFToken": Cookie.get("csrftoken") || "",
      },
    })
    .then((response) => response.data);


// export const getUploadURL = () =>
//   instance
//     .post(`medias/photos/get-url`, null, {
//       headers: {
//         "X-CSRFToken": Cookie.get("csrftoken") || "",
//       },
//     })
//     .then((response) => response.data);

// 계속 에러가 발생해서 수정한 코드 입니다. 
// 바로 위의 'export const getUploadURL' 코드는 니코 강의 원본코드입니다. 
export interface IUploadURLResponse {
  uploadURL: string;
}

export const getUploadURL = (): Promise<IUploadURLResponse> => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    instance
      .post(`medias/photos/get-url`, null, {
        headers: {
          "X-CSRFToken": Cookie.get("csrftoken") || "",
        },
      })
      .then((response) => resolve(response.data))
      .catch((error) => reject(error));
  });
};

export interface IUploadImageVarialbes {
  file: FileList;
  uploadURL: string;
}
export const uploadImage = ({ file, uploadURL }: IUploadImageVarialbes) => {
  const form = new FormData();
  form.append("file", file[0]);
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    axios
    .post(uploadURL, form, {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
      },
    })
    .then((response) => resolve(response.data))
    .catch((error) => reject(error));
  });
};
```

I saw the error below:
[image]

error_messages ->

```
ERROR in src/routes/UploadPhotos.tsx:41:7
TS2322: Type '() => Promise<IUploadURLResponse>' is not assignable to type 'MutationFunction<IUploadURLResponse, void>'.
  Type 'Promise<import("C:/Users/king/Desktop/20231072 NICO django react airbnbcloning again/02 \uB098\uC758 \uD559\uC2B5 \uCF54\uB4DC/FrontEnd/20231030FrontEnd/src/api").IUploadURLResponse>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<IUploadURLResponse>'.
    Property 'id' is missing in type 'import("C:/Users/king/Desktop/20231072 NICO django react airbnbcloning again/02 \uB098\uC758 \uD559\uC2B5 \uCF54\uB4DC/FrontEnd/20231030FrontEnd/src/api").IUploadURLResponse' but required in type 'IUploadURLResponse'.
    39 |   const uploadURLMutation = useMutation(
    40 |     {
  > 41 |       mutationFn: getUploadURL,
       |       ^^^^^^^^^^
    42 |       onSuccess: (data: IUploadURLResponse) => {
    43 |         uploadImageMutation.mutate({
    44 |           uploadURL: data.uploadURL,
```

I cannot solve this problem alone due to my limited abilities. Please help me